# Property of elements in Grothendieck group

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-k-theory, grothendieck-construction

I'm reading Atiyah's K-Theory book and in the section where he introduces the Grothendieck group, he gives two constructions. One of them is as follows:

Let $A$ be an abelian semigroup, let $\Delta:A\rightarrow\Delta\times\Delta$ be the diagonal map, and let $K(A)$ be the set of cosets of $\Delta(A)$ in $A\times A$.

Further down, he states the following, which I couldn't figure out and I hope to get some help with:

Let $X$ be a (topological) space, let $\mathrm{Vect}(X)$ denote the set of isomorphism classes of (complex) vector bundles over $X$, write $K(X)$ for $K(\mathrm{Vect}(X))$, and for a vector bundle $E$ over $X$, write $[E]$ for its image in $K(X)$. Then from the above construction, it follows that if $[E]=[F]$, then there exists a bundle $G$ such that $E\oplus G\cong F\oplus G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element $A\in K(X)$ is a pair $(A_1,A_2)$ for $A_1,A_2\in \text{Vect}(X)$ that is well-defined up to addition by an element of the form $(B,B)\in \Delta$ (where $\Delta$ is the diagonal of $\text{Vect}(X)$); i.e., $A$ is a **coset of the diagonal** in $\text{Vect}(X)\times \text{Vect}(X)$ and $(A_1,A_2)$ may be thought of as a **representative of this coset**.

You should think of such a pair $(A_1,A_2)\in K(X)$ as a **formal difference** $A_1-A_2$. The reason such a pair represents a coset of the diagonal (and isn't simply a single formal difference) reflects the fact that the **formal differences** $(A_1+B)-(A_2+B)$ should be equal for all $B\in \text{Vect}(X)$ (as you would expect). I encourage that you think about this in the case of the natural numbers (***Exercise 1*** below). Of course, remember that the goal of **Grothendieck's K-construction** is to **formally add additive inverses** to an abelian semigroup (or monoid). (It's easy enough to form an abelian monoid from an abelian semigroup (just artificially add an element denoted by $0$ to your abelian semigroup and define addition of $0$ with other elements in the obvious manner); it's slightly less trivial to form an abelian group from an abelian monoid (this is the purpose of Grothendieck's K-construction).)

The map $\text{Vect}(X)\to K(X)$ defined by the rule $E\to [E]$ is equivalent to the map defined by the rule $E\to (E,0)$ in the form described in the first paragraph. (Why?)

So, if $[E]=[F]$ for $E,F\in \text{Vect}(X)$, then $(E,0)=(F,0)$ in $K(X)$; i.e., $(E,0)$ and $(F,0)$ **represent the same coset** of $\Delta$ in $\text{Vect}(X)\times \text{Vect}(X)$. By definition (of coset equality in an abelian semigroup), this means that $(E,0)+(G,G)=(F,0)+(G,G)$ for some $(G,G)\in \Delta$, i.e., $(E+G,G)=(F+G,G)$; and the equality in this line is **equality in $\text{Vect}(X)\times \text{Vect}(X)$**. Of course, "is equal to" in $\text{Vect}(X)$ is the same thing as saying "is isomorphic to (as vector bundles)" so we have that $E\oplus G\cong F\oplus G$ as vector bundles over $X$.

To further your understanding, I recommend that you think about the following exercises:

***Exercise 1***: Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the abelian semigroup consisting of all natural numbers. What is $K(\mathbb{N})$ (as an isomorphism class of an abelian group) in the "cosets of the diagonal" description?

***Exercise 2***: What is $K(\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\})$ in the "cosets of the diagonal" description?

***Exercise 3*** (interesting!): Let $X$ be the set consisting of all nonnegative integers together with $\infty$. $X$ is an abelian semigroup where addition of nonnegative integers is as usual and we **define** $n+\infty=\infty=\infty+n$ for all nonnegative integers $n$. What is $K(X)$? (The answer might be surprising and it's a well-known abelian group!)

***Solutions to Exercises*** (hover cursor over grey regions below):

***Solution to Exercise 1***:

> $\mathbb{Z}$

***Solution to Exercise 2***:

> $\mathbb{Z}$

***Solution to Exercise 3***:

> $0$

I hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer

Comment: You're welcome @learner! By the way, I've added the solutions to the ***Exercises*** above in case you're interested. (I haven't added explanations; only the solution to ***Exercise 3*** might be genuinely surprising. Of course, I'm happy to add explanations or discuss these exercises further with you if you'd like.) Also, I'd like to add that if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space in the context of your question, then we can in fact choose $G\in \text{Vect}(X)$ to be **trivial**! Indeed, there exists $H\in \text{Vect}(X)$ such that $G\oplus H$ is (isomorphic to) a trivial bundle.